# Google Maps zoom controls not rendered properly with Eclipse SWT browser

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xulrunner

I have an Eclipse RCP 4.5.2 (32bit) application on Windows 7 (64bit) which contains a browser control that uses `SWT.MOZILLA` to run on XulRunner 31.0 (the latest compatible as far as I've [researched (yes I know, that link is for Linux)](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux)).

In this browser control I'd like to show a Google Map, which generally works fine, but the zoom controls and some other images are not rendered properly:
[image: Embedded Google Maps Screensho]

This is the HTML file I use to load the map (except for the manual focus on Iceland):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
      #map img { max-width: none; }
    </style>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<api-key>&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[EDIT]** <s>If I use the default browser (`SWT.NONE` -> ie11) the page is rendered properly.</s> I was mistaken. IE (`SWT.NONE`) renders wrong too.

Is there anything I could change to make Google Maps work (while using `SWT.MOZILLA`)?